# How stepper motor torque will behave for two different supply, 24v/5A and 36v/5A

Tags: robotics, stepper

How stepper motor torque will behave for two different supply, 24v/5A and 36v/5A. I am using three Nema 23 , 10kg-cm stepper motors. Using TB6600 Driver which will limit my current to rated current from the supply. It accepts 12-36v and 2.8 is the rated current.

I want to achieve max torque. I went through T depends on Current.
What is my motor torque behavior, when 24v/5A, 36v/5A. Speed will be very less in my use case - kind of robitics arm.

Answer (score 0):

If the TB6600 is current limiting the motor to 2.8A, then the torque will be identical for any power supply that can supply over 2.8A.

Internally I expect the TB6600 is using a chopper driver to limit the total average current - [Chopper driver waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfaoz.png) from https://www.linearmotiontips.com/what-is-a-chopper-drive-for-a-stepper-motor/

So if you increase the voltage supplied to the driver, you might see the torque ripple increase in frequency, but the average torque will still be the same.